# Where should I store my images?

Tags: java, ant, directory-structure

I'm developing a Java application, and I don't know where is the best place to store the images in the project folder. Should I make a `resources` folder at the root, or inside the `src` folder. Or somewhere else ?

Where should it be so it won't make my Ant builds crash ?

Thanks.

*PS : I didn't know if I should post here or on meta. I did it here, but if that's not appropriate, just tell me, i'll know for the next one.*

Comment: meta is meta-about-stackexchange-sites, so this is fine :)

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot crash `ant` unless there is a bug in `ant`. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd go with `project/resources`. I.e., have a structure that looks like

```
+ project
+--- src/        (your source code)
+--- lib/        (your libraries)
+--- bin/        (compiled classes)
+--- resources/  (images etc)
+--- build.xml
```

Here's a related question:

- [adding non-code resources to jar file using Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216744/adding-non-code-resources-to-jar-file-using-ant)

Comment: In addition, you may find it useful to identify the resources folder as a source folder to your IDE. For example, in Eclipse -- Properties; Java Build Path; Source.

Answer (score 0):

A common practice is to create res folder in the root of your project in order to separate resources from the source code. Your ant script is your responcibility, so you just need to fix it to fit your needs.