# How to use Ant include non-java resource files with compiled classes

Tags: java, ant

I have a Java project with all source files in the `src` folder. This src folder contains several packages. Some of these packages/folders do not include any Java code. They just contain some images that I use in the application as icons.

The directory structure is similar to the following.

```
src/
com/
   example/
       pk1/     # This contains only some Java files.
       pk2/     # This will contain some XML and Java code.
       im1/     # This subfolder will contain just the images
```

Now, when I use the `javac` task, it compiles all the Java files into class files and stores them in the destination directory that I specify. However, an non-java files remain as is in the source folder.

I referred this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216744/adding-non-code-resources-to-jar-file-using-ant) on SO. However, I think in my case I want to include all non-Java resource files (without the need to explicitly specifying what files to be moved) automatically into the `build` directory (one that contains all the class files) while following the same directory structure as in source.

Pardon me if I am missing something very trivial, but how do I ask Ant to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the ant [`copy`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task to copy your resources into the `classes` directory (or wherever your `.class` files are stored).  By default, ant keeps the directory structure.

For example:

```
<copy todir="classes">
  <fileset dir="com/example">
    <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to complete the previous answer, the block

```
<copy todir="classes">
  <fileset dir="com/example">
    <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

goes before the task javac

```
<javac [...]
```

and inside the target compile

```
<target name="compile" [...]
```

then

```
<target name="compile" [...]>
   <copy todir="&&&" [...]>
       [...]
   </copy>

   <javac srcdir="[...]" destdir="&&&" >
   </javac>
</target>
```

in my case the attribute "todir" of tag "copy" it's the same of the attribute "destdir" of tag "javac"; I wanted to detailing the answer in order to give you a resolution as immediate as possible.